# KDE翻訳 協力について

Tags: linux

KDEの翻訳に興味を持ち始めたのでやってみたいのですが、(公式のガイドも)見たのですが、分からないので(別の意味で) IRCには参加したもののここからよく分からないです。

チェックアウトまでしたのですが、ここからが分かりません。

Comment: 「何が分からないのか」をもう少し具体的に説明してもらわないと回答が付けられないと思います。参加の仕方？翻訳の進め方？参照した公式ガイドとはどのページでしょうか？ / 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて見直してみてください。

Comment: 既に試されていることと重複しそうですが、とりあえず素人目には https://community.kde.org/Get_Involved/translation をイチから読むのが良さそうです。

Comment: 質問を修正しました。 IRCには参加したのですがここからよく分からなくて...

Comment: 分からないことを質問する手段の一つが、その`irc`チャンネルのような気がするのですが、話しかけてみたりしましたか？

Comment: まだです... IRCでは話しかけてません... チェックアウトですが、svnコマンドでよろしいでしょうか?

Answer (score 4):

下記に翻訳手順に関するページを作成しました。

https://jp.kde.org/community/getinvolved/translation/

メーリングリストの方でも[ご質問](https://mail.kde.org/pipermail/kde-jp/2019-April/001039.html)頂いておりましたが、このページが検索でヒットした際のために、こちらにも回答として書いておきたいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 ページが404で困っていたので...